# Finding the sorted order of an an array of structs in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I have:

```
int  _size; //array's dimension
int _cont; //number of elements at the moment (<_size)
bool _full;

struct elemento {
    T value;
    int pos;
    elemento *prev;
    elemento *next;
    elemento(): value(0), pos(-1), prev(0), next(0){}
    elemento(const T &v): value(v), pos(-1), prev(0), next(0){}
};
elemento *_array;
```

I want to sort it without modifying the original array, except setting "pos" to save the position of the sorted element.  I expected it would be useful to set a next/prev pointer for confronting the two elements' values but I can't figure out how. I made a function

```
add(elemento v)
```

where I manually insert every element, and I was thinking about calling the sorting function at `v.pos=sort_function(_cont)` but I cannot figure out how to sort.

Comment: This is very unusual. Typically you have some type of container which can be sorted. For frequent changes a list is well suited. Storing the position inside the sorted elements need a full recalculating of all positions by every insertation. This is very inefficient. That did not mean it couldn't be done, but it is not very useful!

Comment: This looks like a double linked list, not an array.

Comment: This doesn"t look like a sensible design to me. If you want to sort pointers or indices based on the content of an immutable array, have a separate array of pointers or indices and sort it. Why you would need prev/next is a total mystery.

Comment: thank you, i think i'll use the array of pointers, i thought it would have been more comprehensible with a struct but at the end it was a lot more complex to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array or vector of [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and then [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) that container to get a sorted "view" of the original array.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<elemento>> sorted_view(std::begin(the_array), std::end(the_array);
std::sort(std::begin(sorted_view), std::end(sorted_view), comparison_function_or_lambda);
```

Comment: std::end(*_array) will not work, as this is only a pointer to the first element.